# Using #define to set a variables type

Tags: c, types

So I have a mathematical code that declares a ton of variables with an arbitrary type so that it's precision (double, quad, etc) can be defined. To do this I have a header file

input.h

```
    PRECISION detg;
    detg = 1.0+2;
```

Where input.h is included in a main file like

```
    #include<math.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    #define PRECISION double
    int main(){
        return 0;
    }
```

Compiled with 
gcc testEquations.c -o test

But the compilation fails and gives the error

```
    In file included from testEquations.c:16:0:
    ./GHG_Files/input.h:3:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
    detg = 1.0+2;
    ^
    ./GHG_Files/input.h:3:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘detg’ [-Wimplicit-int]
    ./GHG_Files/input.h:3:1: error: conflicting types for ‘detg’
    ./GHG_Files/input.h:1:11: note: previous declaration of ‘detg’ was here
     PRECISION detg;
```

My question is, why doesn't PRECISION get replaced with double like you would think it should, and why does it give this error?

Comment: Where are you including the `input.h`?

Comment: Side note: it's better to use `typedef` for variable types, instead of `#define`.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a job for typedef

Comment: Your problem (or at least the one the compiler is referring to) is not because `PRECISION` is not replaced with double, but rather your attempt to use assignment outside of a function in the line `detg =  1.0+2;`.  Instantiating data in a header file and a header file without include guards are also bad practice.  You have also completey failed to show the actual inclusion in your code fragment.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put `detg = 1.0+2;` outside a function. Either write `PRECISION detg = 1.0+2;` or put `detg = 1.0+2;` inside your main function.